# Array-bounds warning with character in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When I compile the Fortran test program:

```
PROGRAM character_warning

  CHARACTER(len=16) :: word

  word = 'hi'
  WRITE(*,*) word

END PROGRAM character_warning
```

with `gfortran -Warray-bounds -O2 character_warning.f90`, I get a warning:

```
character_warning.f90:5:0:

    5 |   word = 'hi'
      | 
Warning: array subscript 0 is outside array bounds of 'character(kind=1)[1:16]' [-Warray-bounds]
character_warning.f90:3:0:

    3 |   CHARACTER(len=16) :: word
      | 
note: while referencing 'word'
```

This only started to happened when I upgraded to gfortran9 from gfortran8. I don't understand why the warning is being thrown and would like to remove it so that my compilation is clean. The warning goes away if I lower the optimisation to `-O1` and also if I change `len=16` to `len=3`. Does anyone have any idea of why this is giving a warning and of how to get rid of it?

The exact gfortran I am using is `GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_1) 9.2.0`

Comment: My first guess would be a bug in the optimizer of the GNU Fortran version.

Comment: Very likely, there were similar bugs in the bugzilla before.

Comment: I can't find a duplicate in the bugzilla, it would be good to report it. It is strange that the GIMPLE differs between -O1 -O2 only very slightly in `MEM[(integer(kind=4) *)&dt_parm.0] = 25769803904;`.

Comment: Remove -Warray-bounds from your command line.  That removes the warning.  Or, wait for gfortran 10.1 to be released.

Comment: @steve your suggestion definitely removes the warning. However, I'd rather not resort to that because the array-bounds checking has been very useful to me in the past

Comment: @VladimirF okay, I have reported this to bugzilla here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92422

Comment: @VladimirF, it has already been fixed in gfortran 10.0.0.  The option Mead is using is a GCC middle-end option affecting the tree-vrp stage, which is likely more applicable to C/C++ than gfortran.  What Mead should likely be using is `-fcheck=all`.

Comment: @evets Glad to hear that but I was not able to find any closed reports like that in the bugzilla.